# std::move destroys my object when I push it to std::vector push_back

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, move

I have some troubles with an application that I made. std::move destroys your object when you move it to vector pushback. Here a small example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class FileSetting
{
private:
    FileSetting(FileSetting &fileSetting) { cout << "Copy\n"; }
public:
    FileSetting(std::string name, void * value, int size) { cout << "Create\n"; }
    FileSetting(FileSetting &&fileSetting) { cout << "Move\n"; }
    ~FileSetting() { cout << "Destroy\n"; }

    void test() { cout << "Test\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<FileSetting> settings;
    {
        char * test = "test";
        FileSetting setting("test", test, strlen(test) * sizeof(char)); 
        settings.push_back(std::move(setting)); 
    }

    settings[0].test();

    cout << "Done!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

- Create
- Move
- Destroy
- Test
- Done!
- Destroy

How can I make sure that destroy only will be called when FileSetting goes out of scope and not when I move it. I'm trying to avoid pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::move()` doesn't destroy the object. The "Destroy" you're getting is from `setting` going out of scope.

Comment: But I moved setting to the vector. So move isn't a real move? Is there a way to avoid the destruction of setting?

Comment: @Ordo "Moving" an object doesn't magically transport it from the stack. The object still exists. It's just that moving allows you to "steal" heavy resources from the object. Move operations (ctor, assignment op) must still leave objects in a valid state.